# How to extract a string from another string based up on two character comparison in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

In javascript, I have a string that looks like:

`var str = 'id=126e-90:vj=34566f:ff=1998452'`.

I want to get the value of **id** out of it. That is, `126e-90`.

Could any one please suggest me the better way of achieving it.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method. First, you'll want to split by `:` and then iterate through each key/value pair to get your id

```
var id;
var str = 'id=126e-90:vj=34566f:ff=1998452'
var pairs = str.split(':');

pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
    var key = pair.split('=')[0];
    var value = pair.split('=')[1];

    if (key === 'id') {
        id = value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use Regular Expression:

```
var id = "id=126e-90:vj=34566f:ff=1998452".match(/id=(.*?):/)[1];
```

That will give you the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

There is a few solutions to solve your problem. This is also one of possible ways to get the value of id.
The idea is to find the first index of `:` and `=` in your *id* via [**indexOf()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method, and then to use [**substring()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) method to get the id value between these indexes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p> 

<script>
var txt = "id=126e-90:vj=34566f:ff=1998452";
var indexColon = txt.indexOf(':'); //find index of ':'
var indexEqual = txt.indexOf('=') + 1; //find index of '='
var rez = txt.substring(indexEqual ,indexColon);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = rez;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression (considering that your parameter could be anywhere in the string):

```
var regex = /(^|:)id=([^:]*)($|:)/;
regex.exec('id=126e-90:vj=34566f:ff=1998452')[2]; // 126e-90
regex.exec('vj=34566f:id=126e-90:ff=1998452')[2]; // 126e-90
regex.exec('vj=34566f:ff=1998452:id=126e-90')[2]; // 126e-90
```